# Как исправить искажение картинки, при изменение дальности камеры?

Tags: разработка-игр, unity3d

Обновил Юнити с **5.0.0f4** до **5.1.3f1**. Заходил в раздел *Edit => Project Settings => Quality* (но там ничего не трогал). Хотел посмотреть в целом что это за раздел. И после запуска проекта через N-кол-во времени заметил, что качество изображения ухудшилось.

Было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покопавшись я заметил,что картинка искажается от изменения расстояния камеры. Видно на скриншотах сверху и снизу.

Дальше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ближе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не исключаю,что проблемы в связи с новой версией или всё таки не надо было лезть в *Edit* => *Project Settings* => *Quality*.

Заранее благодарен.

Характеристики спрайта в состоянии покоя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*UPDATE:* Переустановка юнити и возврат к старой версии не помог. + Убирал мипмапс тоже не помогло.

[Сам проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3vixzwih2o0e26/Lost%20Penguin%20v.0.0.6.1.rar?dl=0)

[Делал по этому туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Включен **Generate Mip Maps**. Mip Maps - это уровни детализации изображения. Например, для спрайта 32x32 могут быть созданы изображения 16x16, 8x8, 4x4, 2x2, 1x1. И меняться они будут в зависимости от расстояния до камеры. Что-то подобное и происходит. Использовать Mip Map'ы в 2d стоит только если есть понимание, для чего они нужны. Так что имеет смысл отключить их для спрайтов. После этого остается запустить, сравнить, увидеть разницу (она есть!), и...
2. ...понять, что проблема так и не решена. Изображение по-прежнему искажается при изменении размера, движении и так далее. Все дело в **Pixel Perfect Rendering**, вернее, в его отсутствии.

   Если коротко, то у физического устройства на экране есть физические же пиксели. И у изображения тоже есть пиксели. Если пиксели изображения попадают 1 в 1 в пиксели экрана (или 1 пиксель изображения в 2 пикселя экрана, или 1 в 4 и т.п.) - то такое изображение является pixel perfect. Если же мы сдвинем изображение на нецелое число пикселей (что и происходит в Unity, так как мы используем числа с плавающей точкой для расчета позиции, движения, скейла), то пиксели изображения не попадут точно в пиксели экрана. Вследствие этого значение конкретного физического пикселя будет вычисляться на основе сразу нескольких пикселей изображения, в результате чего при выводе на экран изображение будет искажено.

   Особо от этого страдают pixel-art игры, где используется фильтрация типа `Point`. При билинейной или трилинейной фильтрации искажения заметны куда меньше, но тогда это уже и не пиксель-арт...

   Способов решения проблемы несколько.

   1. Не делать пиксель-арт игру.
   2. Воспользоваться платными решениями из [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/pixel/perfect). Я пользовался [Pixel Perfect](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14498) для личного проекта и был вполне доволен (на всякий случай: я не являюсь автором этого ассета и не имею к нему никакого отношения).
   3. Перенести игру из спрайтов полностью в uGUI. Для `Screen Space - Camera` и `Screen Space - Overlay` есть настройка `Pixel Perfect`. Но, во-первых, я сейчас не могу сказать, насколько итог будет pixel perfect и не понадобится ли дополнительных настроек (например, импорта текстур). Во-вторых, UI не особо предназначен для создания геймплея и могут всплыть дополнительные проблемы и ограничения. К сожалению, по каким-то причинам Unity Technologies не сделали Pixel Perfect Rendering для спрайтов, хотя, на мой взгляд, это является обязательным функционалом для 2d.
   4. Реализовать Pixel Perfect Rendering для Unity самостоятельно.

      - задать всем спрайтам `Pixels Per Unit` = 1,
      - написать скрипт, который в `Awake` берет текущий размер окна игры из `Screen.height` и устанавливает его в качестве `Size` камеры,
      - написать скрипт, который вешается на спрайт и меняет его позицию так, чтобы изображение всегда точно попадало в пиксели экрана, репозиционирование проводить в `LateUpdate`, а потом еще и поставить скрипт последним в `Script Execution Order`,
      - написать скрипт, который вешается на спрайт и не дает произвольно менять его скейл, только увеличивать в 1, 2, 4 и так далее раз с минимальным значением 1,
      - а вот с вращением ничего не сделать, единственный способ - не поворачивать спрайт, а вращение делать покадровой анимацией, ну либо вообще от вращения отказаться,
      - далее все это донастроить, запустить, порадоваться, а потом попробовать на экране старых айфонов 480x320 и на новомодном 6-дюймовом экарне с разрешением 2560x1440, и офигеть от разницы в размерах спрайтов,
      - после чего сделать еще один скрипт скейла, но теперь для камеры: уменьшение `Size` камеры в 2, 4 и т.п. раз.

P.S. А еще есть [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), но это своеобразная вещь и используется в основном для отображения шрифтов.